# 2FA not working after External login on production

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, two-factor-authentication, angular-social-login

I've built an ASP.NET Core website with an angular frontend. It implements [external logins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-5.0) (Facebook, Twitter, Google, Microsoft) through ASP.NET Core Identity. Past week I've implemented 2-factor authentication to be used with the Authenticator app.

I've published the web app to a Plesk environment. When signing in using email/password, the 2FA codes from the authenticator app are working fine. However when signing in using an external login provider, the 2FA codes from the authenticator app don't seem to be working.

[image: External login with 2FA on live environment]

When I'm testing on IIS Express however, everything works as expected, and I'm able to login with Facebook, enter an OTP from the authenticator app and be signed in.

[image: External login with 2FA on IIS Express]

The code for the project is hosted on [Github](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MP.Data/Repositories/AccountRepository.cs). In essence this is what happens:

```
// C#
// The user navigates to the url hosting the `Challenge` for the external login specified
var redirectUrl = Url.RouteUrl("web-v3-account-external-connect-callback", new { medium, provider });
var properties = signin_manager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
return Challenge(properties, provider);

// After the user successfully signed in into the OAuth provider's login page
var info = await signin_manager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
var user = await user_manager.FindByLoginAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey);
// ...
var signinResult = await signin_manager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, true, user.Bypass2faForExternalLogin);
if (signinResult.Succeeded) {
    // ...
} else if (signinResult.RequiresTwoFactor) {
    return View(new ExternalLoginResultVM {
        Status = LoginStatus.RequiresTwoFactor
    });
}


// Angular
// The above MVC response is messaged to the angular app, to which the angular app detects
// that it needs to show the page to ask for the 2-factor verification code
socialLoginDone(result: LoginResult) {
    switch (result.status) {
        case LoginStatus.requiresTwoFactor: {
            this.router.navigate(['/account', 'two-factor'], {
                queryParams: { return: this.returnUrl }
            });
            break;
        }
    }
}

// After  the user entered the verification code, an ajax is being sent
verifyCode() {
    this.httpClient.post<string[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/web/${this.apiVersion}/Account/two-factor-login`, {
        code: this.setupCode,
        remember: false
    }).subscribe((backupCodes) => {
        this.accountService.currentUser().then((user) => {
            this.loginComplete.next(user);
            this.router.navigateByUrl(this.returnUrl);
        });
    });
    return false;
}

// C#
// performing the following code, which is also used for PasswordSignin
// https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MP.Data/Repositories/AccountRepository.cs#L453
var user = await signin_manager.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync();
var result = await signin_manager.TwoFactorAuthenticatorSignInAsync(authenticatorCode, true, remember);
// This doesn't succeed for external login, on live environment.
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    return userMapper.Entity2Dto(user, true);
}
else
{
    throw new LoginException();
}
```

Why isn't this working? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you cannot call `ExternalLoginSigninAsync` from a subdomain, and `TwoFactorAuthenticatorSignInAsync` from the main domain. So now I just have to find a way to open an URL from the web browser, and prevent it from opening in the PWA...